# What algorithm to use for finding empty areas in 2D?

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d

I have 3d elements (triggers) that spawn content boxes when clicking on them. I am searching for an **algorithm that spawns elements in an empty area close to the trigger**. A 2d approach might be enough since the content boxes need to face the user. 
The spawned content box should neither overlap the trigger object, nor other 3d elements / contentboxes.

***Example***: 
If the trigger is a long vertical tube, the first contentbox might spawn to the left of it, the next one would spawn to the right since the left is already occupied with contentbox 1. The third contentbox might then spawn above/below the first contentbox or if there is other stuff in the way then to the left of the first contentbox.

This should work in realtime, it doesnt have to be the actual closest point but should aim for keeping everything closely together. I assume that this is a problem many people solved before me but somehow I couldnt find sufficient information, maybe I am lacking the correct search terms, I am happy to hear about different approaches, hints & ideas..

Thanks

friday

Comment: An idea for you.Map your 2d environment to a grid and set the appropriate granularity.The zero-value in grid means empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a grid on the existed points in the plane or space. This grid could be two perpendicular line on each existed point. After that, create a tree to search on this space. Or just create a kd-tree on these points. Youcan find more about these in computational geometry context.